# Improving the performance of a DataTable to export a .CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datatable, export-to-excel

The code I have is taking too long to export the .CVS, we are talking about several minutes. The query takes a few seconds to execute in SQL.

This is what I have right now to populate the DT:

```
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlString, myConnectionString))
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE1", Date1);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE2", Date2);
            myCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
            myConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
                myTable.Load(myReader);
                return myTable;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is what I use to create the .CVS file:

```
protected void ExportToCSV(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = ContactProvider.GetDataTable(Date1, Date2);
    DataRow row;
    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in dt.Columns) col.ReadOnly = false;
    //I use this to change the value of the columns, because EXCEL changes the string to a date -.-
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        row = dt.Rows[i];            
        if (dt.Rows[i][5].ToString() == "MAR2")
        {
            row[5] = "=\"MAR2\"";
        }
        if (dt.Rows[i][5].ToString() == "MAR1")
        {
            row[5] = "=\"MAR1\"";
        }
    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=Report.csv");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/text";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        sb.Append(dt.Columns[k].ColumnName + ',');
    }
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            sb.Append(dt.Rows[i][k].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',');
        }
        sb.Append("\r\n");
    }
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Is there a way I can improve the performance of those methods so I can populate the DT and export the .CVS as fast as possible?

Thanks for helping, I really need to improve this thing!

Comment: Take a look at SSIS it will perform this operation much fater then you can via C# code.  However you could go straight from the DataReader to the CSV rather than having the convert the DataReader to the DataTable and then the DataTable to a CSV file.

Comment: try Filehelpers http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest as optimize (and without know the rest of the database fetch speed), **to direct write to the output stream.**

Do not use a buffer and a StringBuilder to first make it on memory and then write it, but direct send them to the client as:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
// important !, send them as you make them.
Response.Buffer = false;   

for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
{
    Response.Output.Write(dt.Columns[k].ColumnName);
    Response.Output.Write(',');
}
Response.Output.Write("\r\n");
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        Response.Output.Write(dt.Rows[i][k].ToString().Replace(",", ";"));
        Response.Output.Write(',');
    }
    Response.Output.Write("\r\n");
}
```

With that you can avoid a lot of memory eat on server side, a lot of processing speed that connect the one string with the other, and the user/program see the results as you creates them and not wait to first make it, then send them.

And do not use an aspx page, bug a handler to send them.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the first for-loop away, and move the if's from there to the last for-loop, you will see some improvement. Also; make the if's into ´if, else if´, to cut down the number of ifs that must be evaluated on each iteration.

I can't realy understand the need to replace comma with semicolon - I think it would be better if you wrapped each cell in quotation marks:

```
for(...)
    if (...)
    else if (...)
    else
        sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\",", dt.Rows[i][k].ToString());   
}
//remove trailing comma:
sb.length--
//Append linebreak:
sb.AppendLine();
```